# MongoDB - Query to fetch all related documents with same relation

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a student document that looks something like that:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "full_name": "John doe",
    "gpa": 87,
    "class_id": 17
  }
```

My input is one student_id and i need to fetch all of the students from the same class.

I can of course first fetch the student by it's id and then fetch all of the related students by the class_id, but that would take 2 queries.

The question is, can I do it using only one query that returns me an array of all the class students (including the student with the student_id I have as an input)?

Comment: can you post your class data also

Comment: You can use mongoose and it's `populate` method. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: @varman just class_id, nothing more, just something to group my students by.
SandipNirmal -  how can I use it here ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of non relational databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can group by class_id, so all students are divided into class. Then match the student_id to get all students of that class.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$class_id",
      students: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "students._id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iGDqJdgilbn)

Comment: Thanks, that works. the only thing that I have to change here is to get a response that consists of multiple records instead of one, and here there there is one record grouped by "_id" and another key named "students", I need the response to include only what's under "students" in your solution. is it possible?

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/zgjrXf016aR help u?

Comment: @verman Yes! exactly the result i wanted, but now i have another issue.
Because the students collection is very big the $group action takes a lot of memory, and i don't wanna set { allowDiskUse:true }.
Is there a way to only select the right ones instead of first grouping everything?
Just wanna figure out if the most efficient way for it is actually 2 queries.
(sry for nagging you btw)